# How enumerate/count all parameters presents on a query with PHP PDO?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have the following query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM a_table WHERE col1=:param1 AND col2=:param2 OR col3=:param3"
```

Does PHP PDO (or any other thing/library) have some function that lists all parameters names presents on this query, that writing something like this:

```
print_r(list_query_parameters($query));
```

Produces a output like this:

```
Array ( [0] => :param1 [1] => :param2 [2] => :param3 )
```

Comment: If you have a hard-coded query, why do you need this?  Just trying to understand what you are trying to do here better.

Comment: You could write your own if you wanted. Regex on the query string for all strings starting with an equals colon?

Comment: I don't know the parameters of my query and my queries changes every-time, and I need fill the parameters these queries using cookies with the same name of the parameter.

Comment: Do really mean "How do I write a dynamic query with an unknown number of parameters"?

Comment: @Jimbo it's more difficult than that.  Consider `where col1='abc=:def' and col2=:abc and col3=? and col4='xyz=?'` - you do want to pick up the second `=:`and the first `=?`, but not all of them.  Not to say that it can't be done.

Comment: @davidstrachan No, I need write a logic that will receive dynamic query strings made by another system (each query with a know number of parameters), list the parameters presents on each query, and decide how fill these parameters.

Comment: @AleksG maybe it can be done, excluding everything inside single quotes or double quotes, and doing the search with the resulting string, do you agree?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT:Final solution to the answer (see below for other alternatives)

**Function**

```
function list_query_parameters($query) {
    preg_match_all('/=(:\w+)/', $query, $params, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
    return $params[1]
}
```

Usage:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM a_table WHERE col1=:param1 AND col2=:param2 OR col3=:param3"
print_r(list_query_parameters($query));
```

**Program Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => :param1
    [1] => :param2
    [2] => :param3
)
```

**[DEMO](https://eval.in/142494)**

---

You can also make use of [debugDumpParams()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.debugdumpparams.php) for that

```
$stmt->debugDumpParams();
```

> **Description**
>
> public void PDOStatement::debugDumpParams ( void ) Dumps the
>   informations contained by a prepared statement directly on the output.
>   It will provide the SQL query in use, the number of parameters used
>   (Params), the list of parameters, with their name, type (paramtype) as
>   an integer, their key name or position, and the position in the query
>   (if this is supported by the PDO driver, otherwise, it will be -1).

---

**Things to note:**

You can only get the dumps after you run `execute()` so your code would look like this:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query)
$stmt->execute($params);
$stmt->debugDumpParams();
```

---

`debugDumpParams()` is not doing what you really wanted.

I just wrote this function that should do what you wanted.

please note it is quick and dirty:

**function**

```
function list_query_parameters($query) {
$params = explode(":", $query);
unset($params[0]);
foreach ($params as $param) {
    $param = split(" ", $param);
    $result[] = $param[0];
}

return $result;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM a_table WHERE col1=:param1 AND col2=:param2 OR col3=:param3"
print_r(list_query_parameters($query));
```

**Output**

```
Array ( [0] => param1 [1] => param2 [2] => param3 )
```

**[DEMO](https://eval.in/142063)**

---

**Using Regex:**

Here is the ReGex

```
preg_match_all('/\s*\w+\s*[=<>]\s*\:(\w+)/', $subject, $matches); 
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Comment: I wonder if any of upvoters ever tried this function himself.

Comment: Hm... I have `$stmt = $db->prepare("select * from scenario where _id=:id")`.  Calling `$stmt->debugDumpParams` says there are 0 parameters.

Comment: @AleksG, you need to do that after `execute()` I do it all the time

Comment: After `execute` defeats the purpose of the original question.  I can see how it would be very useful to do this before binding the parameters - if the sql is built dynamically based on user's input - you don't know how many parameters you have - hence the need to check.

Comment: Oh, and you may want to add to your answer that this only works after executing the statement.

Comment: @AleksG ok , I expanded on my answer to make sure it is noted

Comment: @FabioLG I created a custom function for you as I could not find a PDO one that could do this before executing, please see my update.

Comment: @meda, sorry, I pressed Enter and my comment was splitted

@meda do you see what @AleksG replaying to @Jimbo?

I tested the idea of @Jimbo and did 
`$pattern = '#[:][a-zA-Z0-9_]+#';
preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches);
print_r($matches);` 

and I got all named parameters, including things that aren't parameters, getting a result near of your function.

Comment: @meda I did this: `$subject = "SELECT * FROM a_table WHERE something='col1=:param1' AND col2=:param2 OR col3=:param3";
$pattern = "^([\"'])(?:(?=(\\\\?))\\2.)*?\\1^";
$subject = preg_replace($pattern, "", $subject);
$pattern = '#[:][a-zA-Z0-9_]+#';
preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches);
print_r($matches);` and I got only param2 and param3 as output